# python3.7 & pandas - use column value in row as lookup value to return different column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a tricky situation - tricky for me since I'm really new to python.  I've got a dataframe in pandas and I need to logic my way through building a new column that will be used later in a data match from a difference source.  Basically, the picture tells what I can't figure out.

For any of the LOW labels I need to retrieve their MID_LEVEL label and copy it to a new column.  The DESIRED OUTPUT column is what I need to create.

You can see that the LABEL_PATH is formatted in a way that I can use the first 9 digits as a "lookup" to find the corresponding LABEL, but I can't figure out how to achieve that.  As an example, for any row that the LABEL_PATH starts with "0.02.0004" the desired output needs to be "MID_LEVEL1".

This dataset has around 25k rows, so wanted to avoid row iteration as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chosing a similar example as you did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["1","1.1","1.1.1","1.1.2","2"],"b":range(5)})

df["c"] = np.nan
mask = df.a.apply(lambda x: len(x.split(".")) < 3)
df.loc[mask,"c"] = df.b[mask]
df.c.fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
```

Most of the magic takes place in the line where `mask` is defined, but it's not that difficult: if the value in `a` gets split into less than 3 parts (i.e., has at most one dot), mark it as `True`, otherwise not.

Use that mask to copy over the values, and then fill unspecified values with valid values from above.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this and all I can get it to do is copy over the "LABEL" into the "DESIRED" column.

Comment: I got it!  Thank you for your starting point.  I changed the mask to be just a simple len statement since my data is nicely formatted with static data lengths!  so it now reads:  mask= df.a.apply(lambda x: len(x) <= 9)

Comment: @J.Roybomb Glad you got it running! Right, in your case length alone works fine. To get the `split` solution running, you would have needed to change the `3` to a `4`, because your numbers have one *tier* more than those in my example. Feel free to accept this answer as solution if you think that's appropriate. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this data for comparison :

```
test_dict = {"label_path": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "label": ["low1", "low2", "mid1", "mid2", "high1", "high2"], "desired_output": ["mid1", "mid2", "mid1", "mid2", "high1", "high2"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
```

Which gives :

```
    label_path  label   desired_output
0   1           low1    mid1
1   2           low2    mid2
2   3           mid1    mid1
3   4           mid2    mid2
4   5           high1   high1
5   6           high2   high2
```

With a bit ogf logic and a merge :

```
desired_label_df = df.drop_duplicates("desired_output", keep="last")
desired_label_df = desired_label_df[["label_path", "desired_output"]]
desired_label_df.columns = ["desired_label_path", "desired_output"]
df = df.merge(desired_label_df, on="desired_output", how="left")
```

Gives us :

```
label_path  label   desired_output  desired_label_path
0   1       low1    mid1            3
1   2       low2    mid2            4
2   3       mid1    mid1            3
3   4       mid2    mid2            4
4   5       high1   high1           5
5   6       high2   high2           6
```

Edit: if you want to create the desired_output column, just do the following :

```
df["desired_output"] = df["label"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("low", "mid"))
```

Comment: I didn't explain it well enough.  The desired output is what I want to create.  I need to 'find' the MID level label for each LOW level label.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I added in the edit. You might be able to do better than an apply function, but this will surely work.